# Model attributes null, even after mapping

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm implementing a custom Adapter for non-conforming JSON data. The data is being pulled in, but the attributes are not being materialized. I have the following map:

```
// map function has not been overridden - RESTAdapter is super.
DS.ArcGisAdapter.map("App.Cai", {
  caiId: { key: "CAIID" },
  name: { key: "ANCHORNAME" }
});
```

And for my primary key:

```
App.restSerializer.configure("App.Cai", {
  primaryKey: "CAIID"
});
```

With `App.Cai` (the model) like this:

```
var attr = DS.attr,
  belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;

App.Cai = DS.Model.extend({
  caiId: attr("string"),
  name: attr("string")
});
```

From my template I'm getting this data (shortened for presentation) via `{{debugger}}` & `{{log item}}`:

```
_data: {
  attributes: {
   caiId: null
   name: null
  },
  id: null
},
id:"130012000149"
```

As you can see, the id is coming through on the top level, but down below it's not mapped to `caiId` nor is the `name` there. Below is the `findQuery` function from my custom adapter:

```
findQuery: function(store, type, query, recordArray) {
  var root = this.rootForType(type),
    transformedJSON = {},
    adapter = this,
    rejectionHandler = function (reason) {
      Ember.Logger.error(reason, reason.message);
      throw reason;
    };

  return this.ajax(this.buildURL(root), "GET", {
    data: query
  }).then(function(json){
    var feature,
      index = 0;

    root = root + "s";
    transformedJSON[root] = [];

    for(;index < json.features.length; index++) {
      feature = json.features[index];
      transformedJSON[root].push(feature.attributes);
    }

    adapter.didFindQuery(store, type, transformedJSON, recordArray);
  }).then(null, rejectionHandler);
}
```

Any ideas are welcome! Thanks :)
P.S. Let me know if you need any other information.

**Edit**: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/knownasilya/5759147) to JSON data pre/post transform.

**Edit 2:** I came up with a hack, but this doesn't fix the issue.

I extended the JSONSerializer and set it as the serializer for my adapter.
I had to implement the `keyForAttributeName` hook, which is the fallback if the mappings don't return anything. Here's my implementation:

```
keyForAttributeName: function (type, name) {
  var attributes = (Ember.meta(DS.ArcGisAdapter, true)["DS.Mappable"] || {}).attributes,
    guid = Ember.guidFor(type.toString()),
    result = name;

  if (attributes && guid) {
    result = attributes.values[guid][name].key;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Still looking for any help as to why the map is missing for my model.

Comment: How does your model `App.Cai` look like?

Comment: @intuitivepixel I've updated my question to reflect the model as well.

Comment: Still looking for some input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you a have model `id` conflict in you mappings. In `ember-data` when you define a model you don't need to define the `id` field at all if you API respnse JSON's `id` field is called `id`. Therefore I think your model definition and your mappings are slightly wrong.

Try to define things like the following excluding the `id`, since this will be defined with the `primaryKey` override. So this let's us with the following:

Your mappings

```
DS.ArcGisAdapter.map("App.Cai", {
  name: { key: "ANCHORNAME" }
});
```

the model:

```
var attr = DS.attr;
App.Cai = DS.Model.extend({
  name: attr("string")
});
```

and the adapter `primaryKey` override:

```
App.restSerializer.configure("App.Cai", {
  primaryKey: "CAIID"
});
```

this way your `CAIID` will then be set automatically to the `id` field of your model.

Let me know if it helps solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help, the `caiId` is gone from `_data`, but the `name` is still `null`. The `id` on the top level is still correct.

Comment: can you show how your original JSON coming back from the backend looks like?

Comment: Here is a gist, showing my original payload and after it has been transformed in the `findQuery` function above: https://gist.github.com/knownasilya/5759147

Comment: Looks like `mappingForType` function in the DS.Serializer doesn't return the mappings I set. The mappings variable is basically blank (has `keys` and `values` properties, but they are blank).